# Get list of column from query without run the query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated query like this:

`select * from (select id,name left join) union from left join...`

I want to get the list of column that this query will give me, without run the query it self.

I can do something like that:

`... limit 1`

But it will run the query. I searching for a solution that will work fast, without run the query, but tell me the columns that will returned from the query.

Comment: Please show your full query.  Also I think you should not be relying on this logic for your app layer.

Comment: Given that the list of columns can be known only after running the query, this is probably not possible. Maybe caching the column list from the last time you ran the query might help?

Comment: limit 0 would work? I've never tried.

Comment: Yes `limit 0` works. I'm not suring that it is not running the query

Answer (score 0):

one possible way to achieve that would be to parse your query, find all tables and query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html) table, but this might be complicated.